# camel aws2-s3 component - producer prefix option on upload

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-camel

I am trying to use camel (3.7.5) aws2-s3 component to upload a file to AWS S3 storage. Consuming works just fine with bucket being configured using specific prefix as component's consumer option - access credentials are therefore correct (accessKey and secretKey). However, producer does not work leaving me with AccessDenied 403. I suspect that it is due to invalid prefix/path configured on producer: on consumer if I set invalid prefix I get identical error (403). On the producer I tried to use the same 'prefix' option but apparently that does not work/the docs also mention "prefix" as only consumer option. How do I set prefix for producer properly?

That works:

```
     from("aws2-s3://MY_BUCKET?" + 
     "region=eu-central-1" +
     "&accessKey=RAW(XXX)" +
     "&secretKey=RAW(YYY)" +
     "&prefix=MY_PREFIX").log("tick");
```

That does not work (403):

```
from("timer://foo?fixedRate=true&period=5000").routeId("aws-route")
    .setHeader(AWS2S3Constants.KEY, simple("TEST.xml"))     
    .setBody(simple("Hello"))
    .to("aws2-s3://MY_BUCKET?"
            + "region=eu-central-1"
            + "&prefix=MY_PREFIX"
            + "&accessKey=RAW(XXX)"
            + "&secretKey=RAW(YYY)");

Caused by: software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception: Access Denied (Service: S3, Status Code: 403, Request ID: JMCHHA87HN67C2B6, Extended Request ID: 6dEH4iuPXS4dgbJUCtHqw2gfmGuwgbw1cJcvevWpBCnZWJxjCg9oyd1MGWJh++pe2HIe1rT2dws=)
at software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.xml.internal.unmarshall.AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.handleErrorResponse(AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.java:156)
at software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.xml.internal.unmarshall.AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.handleResponse(AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.java:106)
at software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.xml.internal.unmarshall.AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.handle(AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.java:84)
at software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.xml.internal.unmarshall.AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.handle(AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.java:42)
at software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.client.handler.AwsSyncClientHandler$Crc32ValidationResponseHandler.handle(AwsSyncClientHandler.java:94)
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseClientHandler.lambda$successTransformationResponseHandler$6(BaseClientHandler.java:252)
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.HandleResponseStage.execute(HandleResponseStage.java:40)
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.HandleResponseStage.execute(HandleResponseStage.java:30)
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.java:73)
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.java:42)
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.execute(TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.java:77)
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.execute(TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.java:39)
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallAttemptMetricCollectionStage.execute(ApiCallAttemptMetricCollectionStage.java:50)
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallAttemptMetricCollectionStage.execute(ApiCallAttemptMetricCollectionStage.java:36)
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage.execute(RetryableStage.java:64)
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage.execute(RetryableStage.java:34)
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.StreamManagingStage.execute(StreamManagingStage.java:56)
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.StreamManagingStage.execute(StreamManagingStage.java:36)
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.executeWithTimer(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:80)
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:60)
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:42)
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallMetricCollectionStage.execute(ApiCallMetricCollectionStage.java:48)
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallMetricCollectionStage.execute(ApiCallMetricCollectionStage.java:31)
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.execute(ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.java:37)
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.execute(ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.java:26)
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.AmazonSyncHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonSyncHttpClient.java:193)
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.invoke(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:133)
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.doExecute(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:159)
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.lambda$execute$1(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:112)
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.measureApiCallSuccess(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:167)
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.execute(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:94)
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.SdkSyncClientHandler.execute(SdkSyncClientHandler.java:45)
at software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.client.handler.AwsSyncClientHandler.execute(AwsSyncClientHandler.java:55)
at software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.DefaultS3Client.listObjects(DefaultS3Client.java:5901)
at org.apache.camel.component.aws2.s3.AWS2S3Endpoint.doStart(AWS2S3Endpoint.java:114)
at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.start(BaseService.java:115)
at org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:84)
at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.doStart(SendProcessor.java:230)
at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.start(BaseService.java:115)
at org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:84)
at org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:101)
at org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.RedeliveryErrorHandler.doStart(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:1487)
at org.apache.camel.support.ChildServiceSupport.start(ChildServiceSupport.java:60)
... 27 more
```

Answer (score 0):

When you set the header

```
.setHeader(AWS2S3Constants.KEY, simple("TEST.xml"))
```

It should be enough to prepend the prefix

```
.setHeader(AWS2S3Constants.KEY, simple("<prefix>/TEST.xml"))
```